# How do I render data from Firebase in vue at page load

Tags: vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to load data from firebase at page load.
The console logs correctly as follows: `{-Ltl2osulqmFnKIRoT5Q: {…}, -LtnKKxEWkEH7DbV7VB-: {…}}`.

I can't however get the data rendered. 
fbData only shows `[]`

This is what I have: (I know that I have to use a v-for loop for rendering, but below is only to see if anything is rendered at all, which in my case isn't)

```
<template>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="cardFront">{{fbData}}</div>        
    </div>  
</template>
<script>
    module.exports = {
        data () {
            return {
                fbData:[],
        }
    },
    created() {
        var ref = firebase.database().ref("Users/MK01111000/cards")
        ref.once("value")
        .then(function(snapshot) {
            this.fbData = snapshot.val()
            console.log(this.fbData)
        })          
    }
}
```

What I am looking for is a way to render my data at page load.

Comment: the console logs the correct data but for some reason it is lost upon rendering

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="main">
        <div id="cardFront">{{preRenderedData}}</div>        
    </div>  
</template>
<script>
    module.exports = {
        data () {
            return {
                preRenderedData: null,
                fbData:[],
        }
    },
    created() {
        var ref = firebase.database().ref("Users/MK01111000/cards")
        ref.once("value")
        .then(function(snapshot) {
            this.fbData = snapshot.val()
        })          
    },
    beforeMount() {
       this.preRenderedData = this.fbData
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you did and changed?

Comment: @L3Von, this unfortunately did not work. It results in `[]`

Comment: @csabinho I have just add some vue cycle . Compare original and my added function and you will understand .